# cgo undefined reference to `mysql_init@4' [windows/mingw/mysql(c library)]

Tags: mysql, go, cgo

cgo undefined reference to `mysql_init@4' [windows/mingw/mysql(c library)]

```
package main

/*
// -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition for multiple definition
#cgo CFLAGS: -I${SRCDIR}
#cgo LDFLAGS: -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -L${SRCDIR} -lmysqlclient
#include <winsock.h> // for mysql-socket
#include <stdio.h> // for c.puts
#include "mysql.h"

MYSQL *mysql,*res;
MYSQL_RES *results;
MYSQL_FIELD *field;

struct Person {
    int id;
    char *name;
    int chinese;
};

void get_mysql_query()
{
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_options(mysql, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, "libmysqld_client");

    res = mysql_real_connect(mysql, "127.0.0.1","root","root", "dongbao", 0,NULL,0);

    if ( mysql_query(res, "SELECT * FROM users")){
        fprintf(stderr,"Query failed (%s)/n",mysql_error(res));
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!(results=mysql_store_result(res))) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't get result from %s/n", mysql_error(res));
        exit(1);
    }

    int number = mysql_num_fields(results);
    while((row = mysql_fetch_row(results))){
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            if((field = mysql_fetch_field(results) )!=NULL){
                printf("field_name is : %s , field_value is : %s \n", field->name,row[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    mysql_free_result(results);
    mysql_close(mysql);
    mysql_server_end();

    return;
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

const (
    maxSize = 1 << 20
)

func Pause() {
    var str string
    fmt.Println("")
    fmt.Print("请按任意键继续...")
    fmt.Scanln(&str)
    fmt.Print("程序退出...")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main start")

    C.puts(C.CString(" C MYSQL 函数查询…… "))
    C.get_mysql_query()

    C.puts(C.CString(" C MYSQL 使用库函数查询…… "))
    // 使用C的函数库 初始化 MYSQL *
    mysql := C.mysql_init(nil)
    // 使用库连接 MYSQL *
    C.mysql_real_connect(mysql, C.CString("127.0.0.1"), C.CString("root"), C.CString("root"), C.CString("dongbao"), 0, nil, 0)
    // 查询函数 int
    C.mysql_query(mysql, C.CString("SELECT * FROM users"))
    // 查询结果  MYSQL_RES *
    results := C.mysql_store_result(mysql)
    // 查询的字段数目  unsigned int
    number := C.mysql_num_fields(results)
    // 查询结果 char **MYSQL_ROW
    row := C.mysql_fetch_row(results)
    // 查询的字段结果  MYSQL_FIELD *
    field := C.mysql_fetch_field(results)
    // 每个字段的内容的长度 unsigned long
    sql_lengths := C.mysql_fetch_lengths(results)

    lengths := (*[maxSize]uint64)(unsafe.Pointer(sql_lengths))

    cfields := (*[maxSize]C.MYSQL_FIELD)(unsafe.Pointer(field))

    rowPtr := (*[maxSize]*[maxSize]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(row))

    for i := 0; i < int(number); i++ {
    length := cfields[i].name_length
    fname := (*[maxSize]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(cfields[i].name))[:length]
    fmt.Print("field_name is :", string(fname))
    fmt.Println(" ,field_value is : ", string(rowPtr[i][:lengths[i]]))
    }
    // 释放结果
    C.mysql_free_result(results)
    // 关闭mysql
    C.mysql_close(mysql)
    C.mysql_server_end()

    Pause()
}
```

I try to fork code and use in Win-PC by blog("https://studygolang.com/articles/02036").
The blog work well in Mac-env.
But I find that it cannot work in Win-PC && mingw,for x86 golang-env.

```
go-env:
   SET CGO_ENABLED=1
   SET GOOS=windows
   SET GOARCH=386

CMD:
   go build -x
```

**It return errors like：**

```
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build465364450\b001\_x002.o: In function `get_mysql_query':
D:/go_project/cgo_mysql/main.go:24: undefined reference to `mysql_init@4'
D:/go_project/cgo_mysql/main.go:25: undefined reference to `mysql_options@12'
D:/go_project/cgo_mysql/main.go:27: undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect@32'
D:/go_project/cgo_mysql/main.go:29: undefined reference to `mysql_query@8'
D:/go_project/cgo_mysql/main.go:34: undefined reference to `mysql_store_result@4'
D:/go_project/cgo_mysql/main.go:39: undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields@4'
D:/go_project/cgo_mysql/main.go:40: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_row@4'
D:/go_project/cgo_mysql/main.go:44: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_field@4'
D:/go_project/cgo_mysql/main.go:50: undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4'
D:/go_project/cgo_mysql/main.go:51: undefined reference to `mysql_close@4'
D:/go_project/cgo_mysql/main.go:30: undefined reference to `mysql_error@4'
D:/go_project/cgo_mysql/main.go:35: undefined reference to `mysql_error@4'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build465364450\b001\_x002.o: In function `cgo_7e231870cb1e_Cfunc_mysql_close':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:61: undefined reference to `mysql_close@4'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build465364450\b001\_x002.o: In function `cgo_7e231870cb1e_Cfunc_mysql_fetch_field':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:76: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_field@4'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build465364450\b001\_x002.o: In function `cgo_7e231870cb1e_Cfunc_mysql_fetch_lengths':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:94: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_lengths@4'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build465364450\b001\_x002.o: In function `cgo_7e231870cb1e_Cfunc_mysql_fetch_row':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:112: undefined reference to `mysql_fetch_row@4'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build465364450\b001\_x002.o: In function `cgo_7e231870cb1e_Cfunc_mysql_free_result':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:127: undefined reference to `mysql_free_result@4'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build465364450\b001\_x002.o: In function `cgo_7e231870cb1e_Cfunc_mysql_init':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:142: undefined reference to `mysql_init@4'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build465364450\b001\_x002.o: In function `cgo_7e231870cb1e_Cfunc_mysql_num_fields':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:160: undefined reference to `mysql_num_fields@4'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build465364450\b001\_x002.o: In function `cgo_7e231870cb1e_Cfunc_mysql_query':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:179: undefined reference to `mysql_query@8'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build465364450\b001\_x002.o: In function `cgo_7e231870cb1e_Cfunc_mysql_real_connect':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:204: undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect@32'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build465364450\b001\_x002.o: In function `cgo_7e231870cb1e_Cfunc_mysql_store_result':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:234: undefined reference to `mysql_store_result@4'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build465364450\b001\_x002.o: In function `get_mysql_query':
D:/go_project/cgo_mysql/main.go:52: undefined reference to `mysql_server_end@0'
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build465364450\b001\_x002.o: In function `cgo_7e231870cb1e_Cfunc_mysql_server_end':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:219: undefined reference to `mysql_server_end@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

*I Really Need Help!*

Comment: Most probably it means `gcc` failed to locate `libmysqlclient.so` (which it was told to link via that `-lmysqlclient`). Basically you should add another `-Lsome/path` option to it where `some/path` points at where that library is located.

Comment: @kostix If that were the case, wouldn't it complain about missing library in favor of reporting missing references? My guess would be library version and includes may be mismatched here.

Comment: In an attempt to make these error messages have more sense to you: "undefined reference" (in an object file—one with the `.o` suffix,—which is a file containing compiled code) means the code in that file refers to one or more external functions (not defined in that file), and the linking phase (which, among other things, is tasked for resolving all such references) fails to find any other object file or library—among those participating in the build,—which defined those functions. Hence the linking fails.

Comment: @Zyl, looks you're correct, sorry. Does it work is you also add `-lmysql`?

Comment: I try to use -lmysql but it cannot work. I try to think about the version and includes...Thanks a lot for your answer...